# How to run two commands in different folders from an executable file?

Tags: reactjs, express, cmd, terminal, automation

I'm trying to create an executable file that runs two commands in two different folders.

I'm working on a react app with an express API and they are in two different folders. I was trying to create a `.bat` file that ran `npm run dev` in my API folder and then open a new terminal to run `npm start` in my app folder but I can't get it to work.

It is important that in opens two terminals in order to keep both processes open.

My code right now is this

```
@echo off

rem Change directory and run command in current command prompt
cd "path\one\"
echo Running 'npm run dev' in current command prompt
start cmd /c "npm run dev"

rem Open new command prompt window and change directory and run command
start cmd /k "cd path\two && echo Running 'npm start' in new command prompt && npm start"
```

Once it runs, it just says it cant find the specified route.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `start /?` and read the output help. There is the option `/D` to define the current working directory for the executable to start which is passed via function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` to the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which is used to start an executable like `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` or shorter `%ComSpec%`.

Comment: The task description is not really clear for me. The posted code instructs `cmd.exe` processing the batch file to start a second `cmd.exe` with the option to run a command line and close to run the batch file `npm` with the two arguments `run` and `dev`. Yes, `npm` is not an executable, it is also a batch file with better file extension `.cmd`. The second `start` instructs `cmd.exe` to start a third `cmd.exe` to process also the batch file `npm` executed with argument `start`. There are three `cmd.exe` running at the same time for a short time.

Comment: The second and third started `cmd.exe` run most likely longer as `npm` starts an executable (`node.exe` when I remember right although having never installed the package with Node.js and npm) which process a script which takes most likely longer. There are two `node.exe` process running at the same time, first started with `run dev` as arguments and second started with `start` as argument. The second `cmd.exe` terminates itself after first `node.exe` terminate and `npm.cmd run dev` processing finished.

Comment: The third `cmd.exe` keeps running after second `node.exe` terminated and `npm.cmd start` processing finished. That makes it possible for you to use that command process for execution of further command lines or just viewing the output to console. Is that really what you want? Yes, than use as first line in the batch file `@start "npm run dev" /D"path\one" %ComSpec% /D /C npm.cmd run dev` and as second line `@start "npm start" /D"path\two" %ComSpec% /D /K npm.cmd start`. That's it. Two `cmd.exe` are started each with its own console window with the title as defined with the first string in `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Mofi I finally got it working!

This is the code I used:

**Edited mistake pointed by Mofi**

```
@echo off

@start "npm start" /D"path1" %ComSpec% /D /C npm.cmd start
@start "npm start" /D"path2" %ComSpec% /D /K npm.cmd start
```

Once again thanks a lot! I now must figure out how to make it run `npm i` in both of them and run the other commands once `npm i` is over.